# One to many relationship, deleting child rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a single parent table, and child tables which link back to parent table with a foreign key.  I'm attempting to update the row in the parent table and all rows associated in the child tables. I can update the parent table row fine, when i tried to update the child tables it creates a new row rather than updating.

Therefore I'm trying to delete the child rows with the code below first, before then adding the new edited rows.  My problem is, using remove() my child rows are now unassociated with the parent table, but the rows remain?  The foreign key has been made null.

My question is, how do i actually delete these rows rather than just remove association?

The relationship is generated using code first approach.

Many thanks

```
     <Authorize(Roles:="Admin, Employee, User")>
    Function SaveEdit(id As String) As ActionResult

        Dim PreSaveBuild As PBBuilds = DirectCast(Session("object"), PBBuilds)
        Dim context = New ApplicationDbContext()
        Dim retrieveOrders = context.PBBuilds.Where(Function(x) x.Id = PreSaveBuild.EditBuildNo).FirstOrDefault()

        retrieveOrders.Video = PreSaveBuild.Video
        retrieveOrders.FasciaStyle = PreSaveBuild.FasciaStyle
        retrieveOrders.FinishesPerEntrances = PreSaveBuild.FinishesPerEntrances
        retrieveOrders.FrameStyle = PreSaveBuild.FrameStyle
        retrieveOrders.MainEntrances = PreSaveBuild.MainEntrances
        retrieveOrders.PanelStyle = PreSaveBuild.PanelStyle
        retrieveOrders.SystemId = id
        retrieveOrders.SystemLevel = PreSaveBuild.SystemLevel
        retrieveOrders.TotalApartments = PreSaveBuild.TotalApartments
        retrieveOrders.TotalBlocks = PreSaveBuild.TotalBlocks
        retrieveOrders.TotalNet = PreSaveBuild.TotalNet
        retrieveOrders.VideoType = PreSaveBuild.VideoType


        For Each item In retrieveOrders.MainEntranceOptions.ToList()
            retrieveOrders.MainEntranceOptions.Remove(item)
        Next

        context.SaveChanges()


        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard")
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these objects from the `DbSet` in your `context`.

Fix this part, just rename your `DbSet` since I don't know the correct name:

```
For Each item In retrieveOrders.MainEntranceOptions.ToList()
    context.MainEntranceOptions.Remove(item)
Next

context.SaveChanges()


Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard")
```